# How to strip HTML tags from SQL Data without affecting the look and feel of the text

Tags: html, sql, text

I am looking to strip HTML tags from a SQL Table column and would like to strip off intelligently. For example the the `<ol>` tags should be replaced with new line character etc. So that the text looks like it was when `<HTML>` tags were present. Simply removing the tags affect the look the of the text. Any leads would be helpful.

Comment: Post your data and code

Comment: Why do you want to remove html tags when storing? If you want them to be seen as styled why not store with tags?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remind me of the old days !

Needed it for internet data mining, The most rudimentary filter I used was this: if you have *only* text and no HTML, e.g. target is Notepad.

1. First, remove everything between `<header>` and `<script>` tags
2. Then insert tab `char(9)` for each `<td>text</td>` delimited text length div 9, or.. a single tab (messy, but consistent)
3. Now insert line break `char(10)` before each `<tr>`, `<p>` and `<br><br />`
4. Finally, remove everything between `<tags>` from your text.

Comment: I think thats quite useful..Many thanks. I think we can also replace <li> with a line break? Will get complicated for ordered list. Any thoughts on that?

Answer (score 0):

You are right, Andrew T ! I forgot to mension the list tag .. and all within [style] can be  completely removed as well.

Please keep in mind that these substitution tricks are techniques from the past: we're only looking at standard tags, you won't be able to always reconstruct e.g. MVC-5 SQL reporting, because the developer could change the style, or the index.cshtml for the table report.

It is always better to get your data from the database.